# Efficient way of passing object between android applications with database

Tags: android, android-room, parcelable

I have an application that shows vocabulary words and it's examples or explanations for 3 levels of a foreign language. Almost 3500 words of text(no image or sound files) stored in local room database. I present selected language level of words on recyclerview in a fragment also show word detail on a cardview in another fragment.

I am planning to show those fragments side by side on landscape and tablet layouts. And i also plan to set previous and next buttons or use swipe to left or right method on detail activity for showing previous or next word on same cardview.(which means i'll have a query by id method on both cases)

I couldn't decide for passing method of the object between these two activities.
Which one is a better approach that passing the object by parcelable or just passing the object "id" and query it by viewmodel from database?

ps. this is my first question after one year use of stackoverflow and english is not mother language. please don't be too hard on me if am wrong at somewhere.

[sample activity images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QSUEl.jpg)

Comment: pass the row `id` and use any DAO method to get the details based on that id

Answer (score 1):

welcome to StackOverflow.

> I couldn't decide for passing method of the object between these two activities. Which one is a better approach that passing the object by parcelable or just passing the object "id" and query it by viewmodel from database?

A big object should not be passed as parcelable. If your object is rather big, go with passing id. 
If it is a small object, like containing just several Strings/primitives, you can pass it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Event Bus to pass data between fragments, activities...: https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus. It's quite ease to use.

Comment: This should be a comment !